# How to write code for this problem to avoid compilation error

Tags: c, syntax-error

Link to the problem:
https://www.codzilla.org/questions?qid=40

Write Code to find average of all elements of an array.

This code is provided and cannot be edited:

```
int  e;  /* Number of elements in array */
int *a;  /* Array of elements */
float average;  /* average to be calculated */
```

This is what I have attempted:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < e; i++)
{
    average += *(a + i);
}
average = average / e;
```

I expect the code to work properly and give me the correct answer but its giving me the following error during compilation which I am unable to debug.

Your code failed to compile!
code_5945838145861895779.c: In function ‘calculateAverage’:
code_5945838145861895779.c:15:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
code_5945838145861895779.c:15:18: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token
code_5945838145861895779.c:15:18: error: expected expression before ‘}’ token

Comment: Where you are asking for input?

Comment: Saurabh ,the platform on which I am trying to run this code has inbuilt code to take the input,further If I try to take input its giving me compilation error.Kindly you can refer the link for the problem mentioned above.thank you.

Comment: Please post the whole code: the compiler talks about a `return` ("...; expected before return"),  but we don't see any return...

Comment: @linuxfan this is the entire code I have written in the editor,but still I am unable to figure out why such error is occuring(eventhough there is no return statement in my code),I would suggest you to go through the link I mentioned above and paste my code to understand more clearly,thank you.

Comment: The site asks me to log in, and I don't want to create an account. For what I see you are right. It is difficult to debug a program you don't see... I hope someone else can help you, but perhaps you should address the problems of codzilla first!

Comment: `* (a + i);` is more commonly written as `a[i]` in C. That's the use case for the syntax!

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of basic issues in your code. I suggest you refer any good `C` & learn how basic `C` program & pointer works.

Firstly, I don't see a `main()` in your code. The prototype of `main()` is

```
int main(void) {
   /* some code */ 
   return 0;
}
```

Secondly, here

```
int *a;  /* Array of elements */
```

the `int` pointer `a` is uninitialized & its doesn't have any valid memory, hence when you do `*(a+i)` it causes segmentation fault, to solve this issue you should allocate [dynamic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) for `a` first.

Thirdly, here

```
float average;
```

what `average` contains by default ? Its some garbage or junk data. It should be initialized with `0`.

Sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  int  e;  /* how many e ? you should assign it here or take at runtime */
  printf("enter the number of elements in the array \n");
  scanf("%d",&e);
  int *a;  /* Allocate memory so that it can hold some values */
  a = malloc(e * sizeof(int)); /* allocating memory for e integer equal to e*sizeof(int) bytes */
  /* check if malloc was successful or not */
  if(a == NULL) {
    printf("memory allocation was failed \n");
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
    printf("memory allocation is success.. Can proceed further\n ");
    /* put the data into dynamically allocated memory */
    for(int i=0; i < e; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
  }
  float average = 0;  /* initialize with 0 */
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<e;i++) {
    average += *(a+i);
  }
  average=average/e; /* average is of float type, e is of int type, doing / operation b/w two different types ? Result may not be as expected due to implicit typeconversion, do explicit typeconversion */
  printf("o/p : %f\n", average);

  /* job is done with dynamically created array a ? Free it */
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP is using the in-browser editor on the website they linked to, which is why there is no main. The website provides the first three lines, which aren't editable. Your answer is definitely correct, but may confuse the poster because of the environment they're using.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewCliatt I was not aware of this in-browser editor.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewCliatt for your solution,my program got submitted!